# Combining multiple cryptographic keys to generate an encryption key

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

We have a system that has several SecretKeys (for example, one for a user, and one for us).  We want to encrypt data in a way that requires all of those keys to be available in order to decrypt.

I think that the correct way to do this is to use a key derivation function of some sort to merge the source SecretKeys together, and use the result a the encryption key.

Given that all of the source keys are cryptographically generated SecretKeys using the following:

```
KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
generator.init(256);
return generator.generateKey();
```

is it safe to just use a cryptographic hash of the source keys, or is that potentially introducing a vulnerability somehow?  Like this:

```
SecretKey secretKey1 = ...
SecretKey secretKey2 = ...
SecretKey secretKey3 = ...

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
md.update(secretKey1.getEncoded());
md.update(secretKey2.getEncoded());
byte[] digest = md.digest(secretKey3.getEncoded());

SecretKey mergedSecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(digest, "AES");
```

Then use the resulting mergedSecretKey in calls to Cipher.init().

Are there any issues or risks with this approach?

Comment: Stackoverflow is about programming questions. This is really a security question about a homegrown cryptographic construct. As such, I think it is a much better fit for [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Note that public key-based key agreement schemes may be much better suited to this type of problem than purely symmetric cryptography alone. I have a hint of an idea of what you're trying to do from the business link on your profile page, and the details of your security/threat model are probably critical to getting the right solution.

Comment: Thanks @JamesKPolk (I've posted over at Crypto just in case).  We need the customer to be able to effectively kill access to their data in our database by revoking their DEK from their KMS (the ultimate 'right to be forgotten') - not sure that public/private keypairs would help with this use-case, but I'm certainly open to suggestions.  We are using public/private keys for authentication to the customer's KMS, but field level encryption is being done with symmetric encryption.

Comment: *"We have a system that has several SecretKeys... We want to encrypt data in a way that requires all of those keys to be available in order to decrypt."* - Usually you use Shamir's Secret Sharing or the Information Dispersal Algorithm (IDA). The secret is encrypted under an algorithm like AES, then the AES key is distributed to users in shares. No one user has enough of the AES key to decrypt. To reconstruct the AES key a *threshold* of users will have to provide their *share*. You set the shares and threshold. For example, 2 of 3, 3 of 5, 6 of 11, 10 of 12, etc.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Use enveloped encryption. It is better to not combine hashes or do double encryption especially the later can lead to meet-in-the-middle attacks.